# Laravel 5.6 Request и Route. Как получить параметр из роута, не передавая его в метод, как параметр?

Tags: php, laravel, ооп, laravel5, laravel-5.6

Всем привет! Копаюсь в Laravel 5.6. Вот столкнулся с потребностью получать параметры из роутов. Знаю, что их можно получить, передав параметром в метод, который вызывается этим роутом.

Вопрос, а как получить его в любом другом методе? Пока что на просторах разных форумов не нашел корректного ответа. Заранее всем спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 0):

Есть класс Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route . Через него можно получить и назначить любые значения для параметров роута. К сожалению, не нашёл в спецификациях, что данный класс имеет статический метод current(). А он как раз и нужен для получения параметров роута в текущей урле.

Если кому-то пригодится, то вот ссылка на спецификацию по классу [Laravel Route](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html#method_getActionName).

**Параметр можно получить, например, вот так:**

```
Route::current()->parameter($name);

Route::current()->parameters();
```

**Назначить можно вот так:**

```
Route::current()->setParameter($name, $value);
```

**Проверить вот так:**

```
Route::current()->hasParameter($name);
```